# Hybrid Text Similarity

Tags: hybrid, similarity

- I have calculated the similarity between two sentences using three text similarity measures.
- Each algorithm outputs a value between 0 and 1.
- What I want is a method to combine the obtained similarity values without using the average or Max methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple answer, you can use the median.  Otherwise, I suggest being more specific as to the similarity measures you're using.

Maybe you could come up with a weighted average based on the level of trust you assign to each similarity measure.  You could update the trust measure over time based on experience with new data.